# Ionic 5 tabs starter: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router

I'm having real issues with an app built in ionic 5 with angular 9.

I have used the ionic tabs starter and every time I try to navigate to another tab I get the error

> Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**tabs-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        loadChildren: () => import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Do you have a `router-outlet` inside `TabsPage` component? Otherwise, could you create a StackBlitz ?

Comment: @Andrei Gătej
The only router outlet is in
**app.component.html**
`<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>`

Comment: Then try to either remove “component: TabsPage” from the route obj, or add an “<router-outlet></router-outlet>” in TabsPage component

Comment: It seems the error was as a result of another error on the page, a broken image link in an api call. I don't know why that broke the router but it's now fixed. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 3):

It seems the error was as a result of another error on the page, a broken image link in an api call. I don't know why that broke the router but it's now fixed.

If you have this error yourself make sure there are no other errors on the page before unpicking the router-outlet issue